# How to solve "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file"?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, jacoco

I have the following in my pom.xml -

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.8</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*test/java/*</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*test/resources/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <!--<phase>test</phase>-->
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-check</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <rule>
                            <element>BUNDLE</element>
                            <limits>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>0.60</minimum>
                                </limit>
                            </limits>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I am running the command `clean jacoco:prepare-agent install jacoco:report` and the build succeeded. However no jacoco report is generated. In the console it shows that **Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file** . I have tried to modify the plugin in pom.xml but no luck.